# quickly package --extras replaces developer email with hostname

Tags: application-development, quickly, packaging

After running quickly package --extras for my project, I've noticed that in project_dir/debian the changelog file has my developer email listed as alex@myhostname, instead of my proper email address. As a result, running lintian on the generated .deb file gives an error stating it detects an invalid developer email. I'm a little confused as to why this occurs since bzr whoami returns the correct developer name and associated email address, and I have added the developer name and email to my .bashrc entry. Is there some additional configuration I have missed? Or is there something I should change in my project directory that would fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that it gets pulled from `setup.py` If you go to the bottom of that file, you'll see some fields which describe your project:

```
###################### YOU SHOULD MODIFY ONLY WHAT IS BELOW ######################
##################################################################################

DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup(
    name='foobar',
    version='12.07.28',
    license='GPL-3',
    author='Foo Bar',
    author_email='foobar@example.com',
    description="Here's my short description",
    long_description="Here's a a more detailed description",
    url='https://www.example.com/foobar',
    cmdclass={'install': InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory}
    )
```

If that's not working correctly, I'd make sure you have the `DEBEMAIL` environmental variable exported in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export DEBFULLNAME='Foo Bar'
export DEBEMAIL='foobar@example.com'
```